# How to determine if a differential equation is periodic and calculate its period?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Assuming I have a second-order ordinary differential equation

$$[\alpha - {\beta^2}\cos^2\theta] {\theta}'' +  [{\beta^2}\cos\theta\sin\theta] {\theta '}^2 +  \gamma \sin\theta = 0$$

Where $\beta^2>>\alpha>0$, and $\gamma<0$ are constants. How can I analytically determine if its solution is periodic and calculate its period?

I tried to calculate the numerical solution ($\beta^2 = 10;\alpha = 0.1;\gamma = -16;$). When $\theta(0)=\pi/3$ and $\theta'(0)=0$ are given, the numerical solution is periodic.

Is there any analytical method to prove it?

Thank you in advance for your comments and help!

**Update**

This example is indeed too complicated, so I plan to assume that ($\beta^2 = 10;\alpha = 0.1;\gamma = -16;$) and $\theta(0)\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ or $\theta(0)\in (-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$ to study it.

My current rough idea is to draw the vector field diagram (make an intuitive judgment first), and then use **Poincare Bendixson theorem** and Dulac's theorem/Criterion.

Firstly, convert it into a first-order equation. Let
$$x(t) = \theta(t), y(t) = \theta(t)'$$
so we have
$$x'(t)= y(t)$$
$$ y(t)' = - (\gamma \sin(x(t)) + \beta \cos(x(t)) \sin(x(t)) y(t)^2) / (\alpha - \beta \cos(x(t))^2)$$

[image]

Comment: It can be difficult to determine if a differential equations has periodic solutions. Usually, not all solutions are periodic. Rather there are relatively few initial conditions that lead to periodic solutions. One way to get an idea of whether there any periodic solution is to look at a phase diagram. If you think there is a periodic solution, you can prove it using a [Poincare Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20in%20dynamical,the%20flow%20of%20the%20system).

Comment: @Plutoro You are right. Although numerical experiments can show the periodicity of the solution, it is difficult to prove it with analytical tools, depending on initial values and parameters. I've been trying, but I don't have a good idea. Let me try the Poincare mapping first. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I have the impression that you can find a first integral from a mostly equivalent equation of the form $(p(θ))''+q(θ)=0$ which can then be integrated to $\frac12((p(θ))')^2+G(θ)=C$, $G'(θ)=q(θ)p'(θ)$. From this it would result that all (forwards-)bounded solutions are constant or periodic.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! The equivalence equation should be found with some variable substitution. But why $\frac12 (p'(\theta))^2 + G(\theta) = C$ can indicate that the solution is constant or periodic?

Comment: If the system of ordinary differential equations is planar (i.e. 2 variable first order system or single variable second order equation) you can apply a combination of the Poincare Bendixson theorem and Dulac's theorem/Criterion to rule out or guarantee existence of periodic orbits depending on the divergence of the planar vector field or if you know the flow is confined to some region and there are no critical points.

Comment: What happens if you use a starting $\theta$ that is larger than $\cos^{-1}(\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta)$, so the coefficient of the $\theta''$ term is negative. In particular, what about a starting $\theta$ of $\pi/2$?

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis Thank you, your suggestion is very good. As I am not familiar with this theorem, I searched on Google and found it to be a great idea. I am ready to give it a try.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you, you reminded me that I need to add some restrictions to the initial parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply with $2θ'$ and integrate once to get a first integral, that is, an expression that is constant along each solution curve,
$$
(α-β^2\cos^2θ)θ'^2+4γ\sin^2(θ/2)=C
$$
As $γ$ is negative, the negated version gives a sum-of-squares with positive coefficients in some neighborhood around the origin $(θ,θ')=(0,0)$. The level sets are closed curves around there. As the solutions follow the level sets, this results in periodic solutions for all initial values in that open set. The frequency depends on the level curve close to the origin it will be around $\omega ^2=\frac{γ}{β^2-α}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first integral is correct. In this example, $\beta^2>>\alpha>0, \gamma<0$, for $(\beta^2\cos^2(\theta)-\alpha)\theta'^2+k\sin^2(\theta/2)=C$, where $k = -4 \gamma$, it can be written as the sum of two positive coefficient square terms. Why do we say that the level sets are closed curves around there? This is because the expression can be regarded as a kind of energy (>0), which remains unchanged on the solution curve of the given equation. My understanding is not thorough enough. Why is it a closed curve?

Comment: Because you have a strict minimum, the function is coercive in some neighborhood of the origin, it is strictly convex close to its minimum at the origin. This all implies that level sets are bounded, for instance in both terms of the sum separately which bounds the whole curve. And bounded 1-dimensional closed manifolds are collections of closed curves. So select only the one that has the origin inside, ...

Comment: I have consulted some textbooks again, such as Arnold's book on ordinary differential equations, which also has similar conclusions about energy level curves. I understand now. Thank you for your help.